# Comparing logistic regression models with paired data, population-averaged estimates and robust standard errors

Tags: logistic, model-comparison, paired-data

I would like to ask if any of you have suggestions for comparing logistic regression models with paired data (3 observations/ID code), population-averaged estimates and robust standard errors (I am using the STATA command xtlogit, pa corr(exchangeable) vce(robust)).

My method for doing it now is probably very dodgy:
Since you cannot do log likelihood tests after pa and vce, I do them for the standard xtlogit models (comparison of 3 models --> manual stepwise backwards).

Q1: Is there a known method to compare the xtlogit, pa, vce models?

- background info:

I would like to compare 3 models, (models 1) all main effects, (model 2) = model 1 + 2-way interactions, (model 3) = model 2 + 3-way interactions.
I have a binary outcome variable and 3 independent variables of interest (we hypothesized that these 3 variables interact with each other). We have 3 observations per participant (one of the 3 independent variables was a within-variable), so we use logistic regression analysis that is clustered on the participant's ID code (xtlogit in stata).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you compare AICs?